# What are the following notations pointing to?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

For an integer array declared as- int arr[4][3][2]

```
&arr 
arr
arr[0]
&arr
arr[0][0]
&arr[0][0]
arr[0][0][0]
&arr[0][0][0]
```

My analysis:

- `arr`:- pointing to the base address of the three dimensional array
- `&arr`:- The same thing as arr just here the array name does not decompose
- `arr[0]`:-The pointer pointing to the first element of a 3 dimensional array that is pointer to the base address of a 2d array
- `arr[0][0]`:The pointer pointing to the first element of first cell of first 2D array of the first 3D array.

Am I thinking on the correct lines?
Which ones out of these are pointing to the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int arr[4][3][2]` means `arr` is `3D` array, consists `four 2D` array, each `2D` array having `three 1D` array and each `1D array` having `two-two` elements.

Let's Have a pictorial representation of `arr` : Assume `arr` base address is `0x100`.

```
arr[0][0][0]                               arr[1][0][0]                          arr[2][0][0]                            arr[3][0][0]
 0x100      0x104         0x108   0x112     0x116    0x120      0x124      0x128  0x132    0x136       0x140      0x144   0x148       0x152    0x156          0x160     <--1D array elements
   |         |              |       |        |         |          |         |      |        |            |         |       |           |         |              |
   ----------                --------         ----------           ----------      ----------            -----------       ------------           ---------------
        |                       |                 |                     |              |                      |                 |                       |
        arr[0][0]               arr[0][1]       arr[1][0]            arr[1][1]       arr[2][0]              arr[2][1]         arr[3][0]               arr[3][1]
        0x100                   0x108           0x116                 0x124          0x132                   0x140             0x148                   0x156            <---1D array
        |                       |               |                       |              |                       |                |                       |
        ------------------------                -------------------------              -------------------------                ------------------------
                |                                      |                                      |                                         |
                arr[0]                               arr[1]                                 arr[2]                                    arr[3]                            <---2D array
                0x100                                0x116                                  0x132                                     0x148
                |                                      |                                      |                                         |
                -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                        |
                                                                       arr                                                                                              <---3D array
                                                                      0x100
```

If you analyse above figure, you will come to know that `arr`,`arr[0]`,`arr[0][0]` and `&arr[0][0][0]` all are `same`, all are holding `arr` base address that is `0x100`.

Note that `arr[0][0][0]` is `value` but `&arr[0][0][0]` is `address` of first elements, so both are `different`.

`arr` and `&arr` also `same` because arr name itself address so by putting & doesn't make any difference.

`arr[0][0]`  and `&arr[0][0]` also same because `arr[0][0]` is one dimensional array i.e `single pointer` pointing to two elements called `arr[0][0][0]` and `arr[0][0][1]`.
as

```
arr[0][0]               ==      & arr[0][0]
*( *(arr+0) + 0)        ==      & *( *(arr+0) + 0)
*( *(0x100 + 0x16) + 0) ==      & *( *(0x100 + 0x16) + 0)
*( *(0x100))            ==      & *( *(0x100))
*( 0x100)               ==      & *( 0x100)
0x100                   ==      & 0x100
0x100                   ==      0x100
```